# What kind of vector spaces have exactly one basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the question as an exercise in the book *Linear Algebra Done Right, Chapter 2*

> Find all vector spaces that have exactly one basis.

Comment: Can you think of a vector space with one vector?

Comment: Got it ,thanks !

Comment: More interestingly, you could also ask about the uniqueness of orthonormal vector spaces: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980808/uniqueness-of-orthonormal-basis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $\{v_1,v_2,\dotsc,v_n\}$ is a basis for a vector space $V$, then $\{v_1+v_2,v_2,\dotsc,v_n\}$ is also a basis.

So $V$ should have a basis of one element $v$, now for some nonzero and non-unit element $c$ of the field choose the basis $cv$ for $V$.

So $V$ must be a vector space with dimension one on a field isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$.

All vector spaces of this kind are of the form $V=\{0,v\}$ or the trivial one.

Comment: Really appreciate it!!

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept question's in stack exchange if you are new to site!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm new to this site, hope to be friend with you ^_^

Comment: My pleasure....

Comment: Technically, the trivial space $\{0\}$ has exactly one basis (the empty set) over any field.