# Uniqueness of orthonormal basis

Tags: orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices, gram-schmidt

i computed the orth of a matrix on matlab:
[image]
Why is it different from http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=orthogonalize+%7B(1,+i,+2-i,-1),+(2%2B3i,+3i,+1-i,+2i),+(-1%2B7i,+6%2B10i,+11-4i,+3%2B4i)%7D?
[image]

Comment: What is your question? Were you thinking that there should be only one orthonormal basis?

Answer (score 3):

Any two orthonormal bases are related by a symmetry transformation that preserves vector lengths and angles. In the case of a vector field over $\mathbb{R}^n$, the symmetry group is known as the orthogonal group, $\mathrm{O}(n)$. If the vector field is over $\mathbb{C}^n$, then it's the unitary group, $\mathrm{U}(n)$. If you're particularly clever, you'll recognize that an orthonormal basis is, when taken as a matrix, is an element of one of these groups. Put in other words, a rotation matrix defines a transformation from one orthonormal basis to another and, as such, its rows are constructed from the complex conjugate of the components of the new orthonormal basis vectors written in the old basis.

So, when we construct an orthonormal basis using Gram-Schmidth orthogonalization, the basis we get will depend on the choices we make in the process. Which vectors do we choose for our initial linearly independent list? In what order to we feed them into the process? The answers to these question are what fix the orthonormal basis that results.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm sure you are aware, the basis for a vector space is never unique, unless it is the trivial $0$-dimensional space. Even when you add the additional restriction that the vectors are orthogonal, or even that they must be orthonormal, we still do not get uniqueness in general. Indeed, if we have an orthonormal basis $(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)$ for a vector space $V$, for any linear isometry $A:V\to V$, the set of vectors $(Av_1,Av_2,\dots,Av_n)$ still gives an orthonormal basis for $V$. So not only are orthonormal bases not unique, there are in general infinitely many of them.

Comment: But how many vectors are needed to uniquely define a basis for an $n$-dimensional space? Clearly if we have $n-1$ orthonormal vectors then the $n$-th is uniquely defined by the requirement that it has to be orthogonal (and normal) to the rest. Is this $n-1$ the minimum?

Comment: Yes. If there are $n-k$ orthonormal vectors, they span a $n-k$ dimensional subspace, so if we take all elements of this subspace to zero by taking the quotient we are left with a $k$ dimensional subspace. Now the basis for this $k$ dimensional subspace can be arbitrarily chosen, so even under the condition that they must be orthonormal it will not be unique, except for the case $k=1$. (Actually, even then there will be two choices, which are scalar multiples of each other by $-1$.)