# Sum of squares of lengths of projections on basis vector is equal to square of norm of vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, orthonormal

Consider a vector $a$ in a $k-$dimensional space, whose orthonormal basis is $\{v_1, v_2, v_3,\cdots, v_k\}$.

It is given that

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} (a.v_i)^2 = \|a\|^2$$

That is, the sum of squares of lengths of projections is equal to the square of norm of the vector.

It is obvious to derive if each vector $v_i$ contains all zeros except an entry which contains 1. But, orthonormal basis is [not unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980808/uniqueness-of-orthonormal-basis).

How to prove the equation for general case?

---

**Notations used**:

$a.v_i$ stands for dot product between a and unit vector $v_i$.

$\|a\|$ stands for distance of the vector a from origin, also called as norm of the vector $a$

Comment: Write $a=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_kv_k$ and compute both sides. Note that $(a,v_i)=a_i$ and that $\|a\|^2=(a,a)$, that when expanded by linearity gives $|a_1|^2+|a_2|^2+...+|a_k|^2$.